# Publish SNS message and test Lambda from local machine

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have an application like this - sns -> lambda - so my lambda python function is invoked every time there was a new message published in SNS.
The whole code works on AWS UI, but I want to write a test function, thus I need to publish message from SNS topic from my local machine that would trigger that lamba I will watch the log in cloudwatch.

I have searched a lot but could not find something that would help a beginner like me. I installed awscli, extension on VScode and insalled Docker. My local machine is a debian(10) pc. Did not find any option on VScode for SNS.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manually test the behavior of your setup, use AWS cli from terminal to publish test messages. See the examples on the bottom of the page: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sns/publish.html

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the easiest way. I can even do this from my python test function too using subprocess.

Comment: If you want to call using Python then you can actually use Boto3 SDK for the same: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish
Many ways to approach the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the AWS SAM CLI to test your function locally against a mock SNS event rather than using a function subscribed to the actual SNS topic.

Using the AWS SAM CLI you can generate a sample event with this command

```
sam local generate-event sns
```

You can then modify it, save it, and use it with the `sam local invoke --event mockEvent.json`. You should then be able to see how your code will behave and view logs for the function.

AWS SAM CLI 'generate-event' docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-generate-event.html

Comment: my version wanted me to use `sam local generate-event sns notification`